# How to translate "if any"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

I'm translating a text and have a doubt. It says:

> Please add a copy [of some specific papers] **(if any)**.

I could mix up the sentence and say: "Si existen [...], añade una copia, por favor."
But it sounds strange, and anyway I want a translation with the parenthesis.

I would say: "(si hay)", but it sound to informal. Other options I think about are: "(si algunos)", "(si existen)". And Google Translate gives me the option: "(en su caso)"

**Are those examples I gave correct?** Are there better ways to translate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por favor añadir copia de [algun documento específico] (**Si hubiera**).

Comment: estrictamente hablando, ¿no sería más correcto el uso del futuro subjuntivo? (si hubiere)

Comment: El futuro de subjuntivo prácticamente no se usa. En las situaciones en las que debería usarse se usa el pretérito de subjuntivo. Curiosamente, esto hace algo más fácil la traducción de las oraciones condicionales en inglés, que también usan un pasado.

Answer (score 9):

You could use *si los/las hay* or *si acaso existen*.

> ¿Cuáles son los beneficios, si los hay?
>
> ¿Cuáles son los beneficios, si acaso existen?

Note that I'm not sure these expression could be used in their respective singular forms (*si lo/la hay* and *si acaso existe*).

Comment: Thanks! I need the plural form, so it must be fine. But can I put those sentences between brackets, or would that make it look strange?

Comment: Putting brackets around it would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the context, but maybe you could use "si procede" or "cuando proceda", which translates to "if applicable"/"if appropriate":

> Por favor, añade una copia de [los papeles], si procede.

Comment: Thanks! And can this be put between brackets, or would that make it look strange?

Comment: To clarify some information, parenthesis are the correct symbol to use.

Answer (score 2):

There're already good answers, but I'll go with my own:

> Por favor añade, de haberlos, una copia de los documentos.

Comment: There are already good answers and I don't know which I have to choose! But thanks for your answer. But I ask the same question as above, can 'de haberlos' be put between brackets?

Comment: @Silke: yes, I think it could be put between brackets. I think it's a bit more *natural* between commas, but you could use brackets, it won't look too strange at all in my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

It depends of text's context as usual, but I'd say, you could translate this one as:

> - Si aplica
> - En caso de tenerlos (regards the documents)

Comment: @DouglasJavier Thanks for the suggestions. But can those sentences be put between brackets, or would that make it look strange?

Comment: "Si aplica" is an anglicism, that's not correct Spanish. You'd say "si corresponde".